# Suddenly "mydomain.azureedge.net" (Azure CDN - Standard Akamai) not supporting TLS version less than 1.2? Any idea why?

Tags: azure, cdn, tls1.2, akamai, azure-cdn

Suddenly "mydomain.azureedge.net"  (Azure CDN - Standard Akamai) not supporting TLS version less than 1.2? Any idea why?
Is there anybody facing same issue?

Comment: Everyone is switching to TLS1.2 for the last 3 years. There's no "suddenly" about this. Major services dropped anything less than 1.2 back in 2016 (airlines, banks, Google, etc). Your code should *not* depend on weaker TLS versions anyway, it should be able to use the strongest TLS version available on the server

Comment: How did you know that this happened?

Comment: Thank you very much @PanagiotisKanavos
Yes we are constantly keeping up with new version. But in some cases here we have to support old clients (devices).

Comment: @AmrElgarhy  We started having cases/tickets from our old clients. 
Also we can check now on - https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest

Comment: @ManishGupta what does that mean? What OS, what language? There are upgrade procedures for all of them and in many case you don't *need* to change anything, the OS will take care of using the best available TLS version

Comment: @AmrElgarhy that's an ongoing procedure for 3 years, since Hearbleed. The question should be "Akamai still allowed TLS1.1?". If you google for `Akamai TLS 1.1 deprecation" you'll find announcements and discussions about this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes the OS is very old on these devices and the integrated web engines is old too.

Comment: @ManishGupta what OS are we talking about? Windows? Linux? Mac? A custom distribution for embedded devices? Did you check the vendor's site for TLS patches?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Thank you very much.. Yes I am on it. 
And yes it is custom distribution for embedded devices.